# Entity Framework keeps trying to get Old Table Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I changed my table name in sql server management studio and now everytime mvc trys to access the user table it sends a query of dbo.Users instead of dbo.User.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

DBContext:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
Imports System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions

Public Class MvcDemoContext
Inherits DbContext

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=MvcDemoContext")
End Sub

Private _User As DbSet(Of Controller.User)
Public Property User() As DbSet(Of Controller.User)
    Get
        Return _User
    End Get
    Set(value As DbSet(Of Controller.User))
        _User = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _Forum As DbSet(Of Controller.Forum)
Public Property Forum() As DbSet(Of Controller.Forum)
    Get
        Return _Forum
    End Get
    Set(value As DbSet(Of Controller.Forum))
        _Forum = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _ForumType As DbSet(Of Controller.ForumType)
Public Property ForumType() As DbSet(Of Controller.ForumType)
    Get
        Return _ForumType
    End Get
    Set(value As DbSet(Of Controller.ForumType))
        _ForumType = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of PluralizingTableNameConvention)()
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of IncludeMetadataConvention)()
    Database.SetInitializer(Of MvcDemoContext)(Nothing)
    MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
End Sub

Public Function ExecuteScalar(ByVal sql As String) As Integer

    Try
        Using comm = Database.Connection.CreateCommand

            Database.Connection.Open()
            comm.CommandText = sql
            Return CInt(comm.ExecuteScalar)

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return 0

End Function

End Class
```

Controller:

```
Public Class ForumController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    '
    ' GET: /Forum

    Function Index() As ActionResult

        Dim forumCollection As Controller.ForumCollection = New BAL.Forum().GetForums

        Return View(forumCollection)

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Have you updated your models?

Comment: Yes i checked and everthing seems fine the error says the object dbo.Users does not exists

Comment: Which version of EF? If you open your edmx, right click and select validate, what happens? How did you create your models? Did you generate from Database? You can try select Update From Database to see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: do a search of solution for Users !!!

Comment: Searched for users and found nothing

Comment: Is this model-first, db-first, code-first EF? What version EF? What actions have you taken to deal on the model side?

Comment: UPDATED: Im not sure what im using this is new to me.

Comment: I get this error - The model backing the 'Forum' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: It looks like you're writing your models, then that's making the database; is that correct? The most recent error message also implies this. If this is the case, I'll provide a full answer since I had problems very similar to this before.

Comment: If so, then you're doing what's called "Code First Entity Framework", just an FYI! :)